# Give access to the website hosted on my webserver to a friend

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, webserver

I am new to web development and I am developing my very first website for a friend of mine.

The site is currently at its first stage of development on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and I would like my friend to see it, but I don't know how can I give him access to it through its Android smartphone.

I thought about using OpenVPN, configuring my Ubuntu as the VPN server, and its smartphone as the VPN client, but I am not quite sure this is the right way to go, or if there is a simple alternative I am not aware of.

If it can be of help, I am using Flask and Python as webserver.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1**

Following **Ryan Doherty**'s answer, I was able to forward the port 22 with my 4G router. I added my private IP in the section under "destination IP" as illustrated in [this example image](http://prnt.sc/2p7nzs) (not my specs!). Is this correct, or should I need to assign the local IP?

Anyway, as I have DHCP actvated, would this be a problem? I don't know that much about it, but I guess the router is assigning a different local IP to my server from time to time/session to session, so should I need to change this behaviour (i.e. using static IP's)?

From now on, I am not quite sure on how to proceed. So here I summarize my questions:

1. Should I change my local IP to a static one by deactivating DHCP on the router?
2. How do I use `openssh` to provide username and password to give to my friend in order to connect to the website?

I hope my questions are clear, as I am not skilled in all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ssh`. It is very commonly used to access webservers when you don't have physical access to the machine.
You can set it up by installing the ssh server on your Ubuntu machine with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Then you need to check if you can forward your ssh service to the internet (assuming your friend isn't on your internet) This depends on your internet plan and ISP. Check if your ISP allows you to host services from home (BrightHouse (now Spectrum) does).
This doesn't necessarily apply to you assuming that your web site is on the internet, it's more for others who are looking at this.

After that your need to forward port 22 on your web server through your router. You'll need to Google how to do this with your router.
Once all of this is done, get your public IP and tell your friend your login info and public IP, they'll login with

```
ssh yourusername@your.public.IP
```

It will give you a password prompt and boom you're in.
You can transfer files with sftp (it runs through ssh).
In order to give him access you can use port forwarding through `ssh` using the -L option. For example, to forward facebook.com to localhost:8080 you could use.

```
ssh -L 8080:www.facebook.com:80
```

or in your situation you can setup local port forwarding through the ConnectBot app
All he/she has to do is go to http://localhost:8080

EDIT:
If he wants to connect through his Android phone, he'll need to use an app like ConnectBot (I personally use it and it's great).

Comment: "I'm not sure if it automatically adds it as a startup service"... Yes, it does.

Comment: muru OK I'll edit it thx

Comment: mmm, in my router's page I only see a 'DMZ' subpage, which would let me add an computer IP (mine for instance) to let it be accessible to external network. Would this be sufficient to tell my friend to navigate to my hosted website doing like "my_ip:port/index.html"? I previously open a specific port for accessing the same website in my own internal network. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't use a DMZ. That's a bit extreme and can be insecure given that it exposes all the computers ports to the internet. Do you have a WAN page? What is your router's model?

Comment: The router is a Vodafone R216-Z 4G WiFi. Unfortunately, I cannot see any port-forward session.

Comment: Unfortunately, Vodafone and really all 4G router's don't offer port forwarding due to the architecture of the cellular network. That would mean ssh, OpenVPN, etc wouldn't work. I guess another option would be to actually get a web server from a hosting provider like GoDaddy

Comment: It seems it is feasable! I had a look at [this discussion](https://community.vodafone.ie/t5/Packages-Plans/huawei-HG658c-port-forwarding-for-tungle/td-p/142998). Will try to move on with the next steps you posted...

Comment: @RyanDoherty You were right, I will accept your answer because I think it would have taken me to the right solution, but I can't because I cannot ask a static public IP for my mobile network. Thanks.